# Добавление значений в таблицу sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3, datetime 


p_d = datetime.date.today() 
p_t = datetime.datetime.today()
p_a = ("20100",) 

con = sqlite3.connect("time77076.db")
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE times (d DATE, t TIMESTAMP, a TEXT)") 
cur.execute("INSERT INTO times (d,t,a) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (p_d, p_t, p_a))
cur.execute("SELECT d, t, a FROM times") 

res = cur.fetchone() 
print(res[0])
print(res[1])
print(res[2])
con.close()
```

Cоздал таблицу с тремя колонками но по какой-то причине немогу добавить в них значение. Постоянно пишет не поддерживает тип. Вчем дело подскажите пожайлуста.

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\YandexDisk\Python\Проекты\Проект Гараж\time.py", line 12, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO times (d,t,a) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (p_d, p_t, p_a))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь передать в качестве параметров вложенный кортеж (`tuple`):

```
In [31]: print((p_d, p_t, p_a))
(datetime.date(2018, 3, 19), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 19, 21, 4, 23, 992898), ('20100',))
#                                                                               ^        ^
```

Чтобы исправить:

```
p_a = "20100"
```

проверка:

```
In [45]: %paste
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE times (d DATE, t TIMESTAMP, a TEXT)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO times (d,t,a) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (p_d, p_t, p_a))
cur.execute("SELECT d, t, a FROM times")

## -- End pasted text --
Out[45]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0xbb097a0>
```

Comment: ну или можно `*p_a`

Comment: @Twiss, тогда уж лучше `p_a[0]` - если в кортеже несколько значений `*p_a` - сломается...

Comment: да безусловно согласен  с этим